# User only access data at specific time set by admin or user

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am looking for a way to restrict user from accessing or updating data before specific time frame which is set by other user or admin despite of time set in locally on mobile phone. I know that timestamp may be useful but don't know how to implement that??

Comment: You will be able to achieve this by using the realtime database rules using the `now` variable - https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/security/database/#now

In the meantime, add what you have so far such as your database json.

Comment: @Callam I didn't have wrote solution yet as I can't figure out it well. Any Code example in android will be appreciated

Comment: Give us an example of what you would like to restrict users from and an example of a time frame.

Comment: User A sets timeline for example 19 Sep 2017 2 pm to 21 Sept 2017 3pm due to which user B  can't perform reading and writing operation on some nodes.

Comment: So you'd like to deny access to some nodes between those two times?

Comment: I  want to deny access except the time interval between between two times

Comment: Can you provide any code example @Callam